# Ugly geolocation message, using WebView

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, xcode

I created an app for iPhone/iPad that uses geolocation via JavaScript/HTML inside WebView. HTML files and scripts are located in app.

When I tap on geolocation button, i see geolocation message, it states that "**/var/mobile/Application/~~~~/App.app/www**" wants permission to use geolocation.

That makes sense because iOS probably wants permission to allow geolocation for the app and the browser wants permission.

How can I prevent this ugly message?

Here are the screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6I4x.png

Comment: Like you said, iOS needs permission from the user to allow location services and this alert will always be displayed the first time your app attempts access to it. So in other words, there is no way to prevent this message.

Comment: Is it possible to change this message? I don't like **/var/mobile/Application/~~~~/App.app/www**

Comment: Maybe you can try asking for permission before the web view so that the message will use your app name instead of that ugly name.